# Extending a Service to add "Internet" feature or using intent action for better performance? Less performance with different services?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, service

I have a Service that run in the foreground. Let's say I have a method like this:

```
protected void performAction() {

        //... somecode1
        //... somecode2
    }
}
```

as I said in the title, I would like to add a feature also to send data to server.
If I do it with an intent action, it would look like this:

```
protected void performAction() {
            //... somecode1
   if(intent.getAction().equals("INTERNET"))
this.clientThread.sendMessage(text);
            //... somecode2
        }
    }
    
    
     public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int constant = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if(constant==START_NOT_STICKY)
            return START_NOT_STICKY;

        else if(intent.getAction().equals("INTERNET"))
        {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to Server...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.clientThread = new ClientThread(handler,this);
            this.clientThread.start();
        }
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

but what if want to extend my service as `ClientService` where basically I just add the ClientThread field and override the `performAction()`, this way I wouldn't need to check the `intent.getAction()` each time the method is called.
However by extending the class I would need to destroy the "father service" and call the "child" extended service.

So, I am not sure which one would be performant since I am new to android.

Comment: Neither.  There's no reason to use a Service just to send a message to a server.  You need to explain your high level usecase more, to see if there's better ways of doing it as a whole.

Comment: The reason I need a service it's because that service is monitoring constantly the clipboard and getting the text from there. I can't do this on an Activity since I would assume the clipboard monitoring would work only when the activity is on focus.